# Autorefresh DropDownJS

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy intentando usar dropdown js para realizar la carga de una imagen, pero al arrastrar y soltar dicha imagen, la pagina se recarga automaticamente borrandome los datos que habia incluido en el formulario, que puedo hacer alli?

Esta es la pagina de la libreria http://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically

y la estoy intentando implementar en C# .Net

**HTML**

`

```html
<form id="dropZoneForm" action="@Url.Action("FileUpload", "Campaign")" class="dropzone col-md-3">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
</form>
```

`

**Controlador**
`

```html
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult FileUpload()
        {
            bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;
            string fName = "";
            try
            {
                foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                    fName = string.Concat(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Path.GetExtension(file.FileName));
                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var originalDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(string.Format("{0}CampaignImages\\", Server.MapPath(@"~\Uploads\")));
                        string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "tempimagepath");
                        bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString);
                        if (!isExists)
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
                        var path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString, fName);
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isSavedSuccessfully = false;
            }
            if (isSavedSuccessfully)
            {
                return Json(new { Message = fName });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Message = "Error in saving file" });
            }
        }
```

`

**Javascript**
`

```html
Dropzone.options.dropZoneForm = {
            acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
            maxFiles: 1,
            addRemoveLinks: false,  
            dictRemoveFile: 'Eliminar',
            parallelUploads: 1,
            dictMaxFilesExceeded: 'Solo se puede cargar 1 elemento.',
            init: function () {
                this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) {
                    this.removeAllFiles();
                    this.addFile(file);
                    //En caso de exceder el limite, queda sin clickearse
                    dropZoneForm.clickable = false
                });
                this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
                    //Elimina la primera imagén cargada, cada vez que se agrega una segunda
                    if (this.files.length > 1) {
                        this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
                    }
                });
                this.on("complete", function (file) {
                    //Los var, son para evitar errores de undefined
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var data = file.xhr.responseText;
                    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
                    $('#Imagen').val(jsonResponse['Message']);
                });
            }
        };
```

`

Comment: Falta claridad en la pregunta y el código que estás tratando de implementar... con eso podríamos ayudarte de mejor manera

Comment: Esta librería te permite cargar varias imágenes si lo deseas simplemente arrastrando y soltando las imágenes en un recuadro.

Lo que sucede es que cuando yo arrastro una imagen al recuadro, la pagina se refresca, lo que hace que los cambios del formulario no se guarden y toque volver a iniciar.

Aquí esta el enlace del cual tome el código de ejemplo (http://www.venkatbaggu.com/file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dropzone-js-and-html5/ )

Comment: He trabajado con esa librería sin problemas amigo, por eso te pido más info, ya que a mi me ha funcionado bien. Lo más probable es que estes haciendo en la lógica que este haciendo el refresh. La url que adjuntaste envía un 404 =/

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera he corregido el link, pero por si las dudas mira http://www.venkatbaggu.com/file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dropzone-js-and-html5/

Comment: Amigo, insisto en que copies tu código en la pregunta formulada, a ti no te funciona, por lo tanto debemos ver tu código...

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera he editado la pregunta agregandole mi codigo.